# Has get_object_vars changed in version 5.4?

Tags: php

I used to get all public vars from a class inside a class with a Closure like this:

```
Class myClass
{
  public $foo;
  private $bar;

  private function GetFields()
  {
    $lambda = function( $obj ) { return get_object_vars( $obj ); };
    return $lambda( $this );
  }

  public function SomeFunction()
  {
    $fields = $this->GetFields();
  }
}
```

This worked perfect, and gave me all public vars while inside a class.

Now, I upgraded my server to PHP 5.4 and I get all privates and protected vars to.
Is that a new 'Feature' or is it a Bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, its a unwanted side effect of moving closures into the scope of the class.

Have a look at: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures/object-extension

In the end I thinks its a **bug** or at least a unwanted 'Feature'.

I'll must think another strategy to find all public properties of a class, while inside a class.

**update:**

this is what I came up with:

```
Class myClass
{
  public  $foo;
  private $bar;

  private function GetFields()
  {
    $fields = [];
    $ref = (new ReflectionObject($this))->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);
    foreach ( $ref as $value )
      $fields[$value->name] = $this->{$value->name};

    return $fields;
  }

  public function SomeFunction()
  {
    $fields = $this->GetFields();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the docs for `get_object_vars()`.

> Returns an associative array of defined object accessible non-static properties for the specified object in scope.

I'm assuming, when you are using the `$this` context `get_object_vars()` is giving you all the accessible properties. Which would include `private` and `protected`.

---

In PHP 5.4 you can now use `$this` inside anonymous functions. Scroll down and look at the changelog. http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

> ### Changelog
>
> 5.4.0 | $this can be used in anonymous functions

Comment: @JvdBerg `get_object_vars()` doesn't return static properties.

Comment: @JvdBerg on a side note though, I think it might be a bug. It is strange that you are changing the `$this`'s context by using a lambda but it still has access to private and protected properties.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the use case of this function in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

You have to cases there, the first one when you are creating an instance on an object and the second one inside a class. Those two cases have different results. The first one shows only public attributes, the second one shows all attributes.

The difference comes from the fact that `get_object_vars()` returns all accessible properties of an object. When you are creating an instance of an object and passing it as a parameter to the function it can access only public attributes but when you are inside of the class and you are passing `$this` as a parameter it can access all attributes.

Comment: But what about the lambda? Has that scope changed from 5.3 to 5.4?

Comment: I don't think so. I have on my computer PHP 5.3.6 and I have this exact results.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, I was testing code from php manual and not yours. And in your case anonymous function, as Baylor-Rae pointed out, can from PHP 5.4 use $this in closures. So yes, the scope has changed in PHP 5.4 for that case.